# OpenSSH Client Options, specify min and max modulus?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

In this answer to "[What's the modp length of diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/39615/98207)" it states:

> The actual selection process is, in OpenSSH source code, in the
>   choose_dh() function in the dh.c file. Roughly speaking, **if the client
>   wants at least min bits**, at most max bits, and preferably n bits, then
>   the server will choose among the moduli in the min..max range;

When connecting to the SSH server, what is the [client side option](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh) to specify this minimum acceptable Diffie-Hellman moduli (key) size, in bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such option in OpenSSH. The values are hard-coded in the [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/dh.h#L49), but updated accordingly to the current needs (currently 2048 - 8192):

```
/*
 * Max value from RFC4419.
 * Miniumum increased in light of DH precomputation attacks.
 */
#define DH_GRP_MIN  2048
#define DH_GRP_MAX  8192
```

Answer (score 0):

BSD ssh client allows you to choose which of a list of key exchange algorithms to attempt to use when exchanging keys with the server, see [ssh_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5)

However, bit lengths are really determined by how your keys are generated. Check out the -b option to [ssh-keygen](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&manpath=OpenBSD%203.1&format=html).

Comment: this is not regarding the authentication keys, this about the internal Diffie-Hellman parameters...(regarding your second paragraph, I do not use ssh-keygen in any of this). i believe internally it has a modulii file to look at.